# Krusader: using Alt+D as a shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In [Krusader](https://krusader.org/), I want to use Alt-D as a shortcut to focus the location bar. This works fine for browsers and Dolphin.  When I set the shortcut for "Go To Location Bar" to "Alt-D", setting the shortcut has no errors.  When I try to use the shortcut, I get an error popup saying that the key sequence 'Alt+D' is ambiguous.

Note that I have to hit 'Alt+D' twice to get the error. This makes me think that I'm colliding with the 'Alt+D' consumed by Plasma.

What can I do to get Krusader to do what Dolphin, Firefox, and Chromium do?

Comment: whats Krusader?

Comment: https://krusader.org/

Comment: Krusader is an advanced twin panel (commander style) file manager for KDE Plasma and other desktops in the *nix world, similar to Midnight or Total

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by now. This is known bug of `Krusader`. In Ubuntu `20.04` the same problem is reproducing.

In `Krusader` keys combination `Alt + letter or digit` is used to navigate through UI (menu items, buttons, tabs, navigation path items). So `Alt + D` is pointing to something in it.

There are many bug reports with the similar problem on [Krusader bugtracker](https://krusader.org/report-bugs/index.html). May be one day this will be fixed. Links to the bugs:

- [Ambiguous shortcut (Alt + R)](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=436613)
- [cant use shortcuts (Alt+E) which conflict mnemonics](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337731)
- [Alt+letter keyboard shortcuts conflict with accelerators](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221695)
- [alt+letter shortcuts are overriden by main menu shortcuts](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185788)
- [Alt-shortcuts dont work with secondary layout](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71147)

Comment: The question is off topic and should have been closed back when it was asked. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close them instead.